# how to move profile picture to a navigation bar when scrolling up?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uinavigationbar

I have created this layout using `UITableView` header and I'm trying to move profile picture when scrolling up and removing full name and Phone number. First screen UI is what I have created and it is made in tableview header and

[image]

I want to achieve a functionality of a second screen when scrolling up.

[image]

Comment: explain in detail your question , are you talking about which layout?

Answer (score 0):

You need add UIScrollViewDelegate to your tableView.
Table view inherit UIScrollView and their UIScrollViewDelegate methods.
So... you need set  like this:

Somewhere set delegate:

```
tableView.delegate = self
```

(I think you mb already implement this because you need to implement UITableViewDelegate methods)
and implement UIScrollViewDelegate method:

```
extension YourControllerOrAnotherDelegateClass: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
       // use scrollView.contentOffset to calculate when you need to update navbar
    }
}
```

inside this method you can get content offset of your scrollView and update nav bar when you needed.